# Using JiraRobot Library but cannot connect Jira in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework, jira

I tried to connect Jira by the below code

```
*** Settings ***
Library         JiraRobot
       
*** Test Cases *** 
Test_Connect_Jira
   Connect To Jira    ${UserID}  ${Pass}  options= {'server':'${ServerName}'}
   Log    Get Current User
```

I got error

```
    [ WARN ] ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')) while doing GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
[ WARN ] Got ConnectionError [('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))] errno:None on GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo
{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}\{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}
[ WARN ] Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [1/3] in 0.531449693973s. Err: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
[ WARN ] ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')) while doing GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
[ WARN ] Got ConnectionError [('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))] errno:None on GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo
{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}\{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}
[ WARN ] Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [2/3] in 3.70011506578s. Err: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
[ WARN ] ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')) while doing GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
[ WARN ] Got ConnectionError [('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))] errno:None on GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo
{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}\{'request': <PreparedRequest [GET]>, 'response': None}
[ WARN ] Got recoverable error from GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo, will retry [3/3] in 50.5519016195s. Err: ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host'))
[ WARN ] ('Connection aborted.', error(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host')) while doing GET https://jira.xxx.com/rest/api/2/serverInfo [{u'headers': {'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', u'Accept': u'application/json,*.*;q=0.9', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.24.0', 'Connection': 'keep-alive', u'X-Atlassian-Token': u'no-check', u'Cache-Control': u'no-cache', u'Content-Type': u'application/json'}, 'params': None}]
[ ERROR ] Execution stopped by user.

Authentication to JIRA unsuccessful. Ensure the user used has sufficient access and that Username and Password were correct


Process finished with exit code 253
```

but I actually manual login by these username and password.

Anyone had experience please help me.

Answer (score 1):

The below keyword worked for me.

*** Settings ***

Library    RequestsLibrary

Library    JiraRobot

*** Keywords ****

Connect To Jira

```
Connect To Jira    username   password    options={'rest_api_version': '2', 'verify': True, 'server': 'Jira URL', 'headers': {'X-Atlassian-Token': 'nocheck'}, 'rest_path': 'api', 'resilient': 'False', 'async': 'False'}
```

Also, make sure that the library is available.

```
pip install JiraRobot
```

Comment: Is it possible to reverie the first code block into multiple lines do that scrolling is not redwood? Typically json/JS can be written on multiple lines for easy readability. It is also not clear to me that "Connect to Jira", "username", or "password" should be included in the code block. It seems to me they might be menu items? . But I'm not familiar with this tool/framework. info looks good, I'm simply questioning if there is a better way to format the info in this post for clarity and visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I can connect Jira right now by use API token instead of password.